# Pagination for single post

Tags: posts, pagination, single

I would like to make my pagination for single post look like this:

[image: pagination with next, prev and links in between and also disabled]

and **not** like that.....
[image: current pagination]

I am using wordpress and for pagination in single post i using the quicktag. Theme is MH Magazine liteVersion: 2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/wp-pagenavi/) can help you

Comment: Thank yu, Pratik, i tried using WP Navi, but it provides for archive pages only, like my home page, category page etc, not for single posts. For single posts its not doing anything i still have the 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 as shown above

Comment: Then you can do it by using css and Jquery. Can you share your site URl so  I can guide you for that

Answer (score 0):

Add following css into it

```
    .pagination.clearfix > a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

For Js/Jquery I need to know the code you are using for generation of the links.

SO I can know if we can add any 'id' to the code so we can manage it with jquery or js

Comment: the <!--nextpage--> quicktag

Comment: So this is used to generate page generation on your post

Comment: Yes, i am just inserting the <!--nextpage--> wherever i need to break the post, for example in text mode like this...

hhdhfhdbfhdbfcbdhbfchdxhfc
<!--nextpage-->

content here

Comment: /***** Pagination *****/

.post .pagination { padding-bottom: 20px; padding-bottom: 1.25rem; }
.page-numbers { display: inline-block; font-weight: 700; color: #000; padding: 10px 15px; background: #f5f5f5; }
.page-numbers:hover, .mh-loop-pagination .current, .mh-comments-pagination .current, a:hover .pagelink { color: #fff; background: #e64946; }
.page-numbers a { display: block; }
.pagelink { display: inline-block; font-weight: 700; color: #fff; padding: 10px 15px; background: #e64946; }
a .pagelink { color: #000; background: #f5f5f5; }

Comment: That is the css, for pagination part

Comment: Ok I wil check it and get back to you